# Integrating Blockchain Technology with Android Biometric Authentication

Tags: android, security, blockchain, android-biometric

I'm working on a personal Android app where security is a top priority, and I want integrating blockchain technology with biometric authentication. I envision a scenario where users' biometric data (fingerprint, facial recognition, etc.) is not only used for device access but also for secure interactions with a blockchain network.

I've researched both biometric authentication and blockchain individually, but I'm struggling to find resources or examples that demonstrate how to combine these two technologies effectively within an Android app. Has anyone attempted a similar integration before? If so, could you provide guidance on how to get started?